# Table in Word document with n columns to fit as per page size and allow truncated columns to break across page using Aspose.words for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, aspose.words

I'm generating a word document using Aspose.Words(Evaluation mode) for .Net in which I'm building a table as following

```
   Document doc = new Document();
   DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
   Table table = builder.StartTable();
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
       {
            builder.InsertCell();
            builder.Write("Column : "+ j.toString());
        }
     builder.EndRow();
   }
   builder.EndTable();
   doc.Save(ms, Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions.CreateSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Doc));
   FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\NewDoc.doc", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
   ms.WriteTo(file);
   file.Close();
   ms.Close();
```

Now this code gives following word file with invisible columns, it should give 20 columns

[image: Table with truncated columns]
.

Is there any way to break invisible columns to next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows can go to next page, not columns, it is the behavior of Microsoft Word. You can change the design and formatting of the document to make all columns visible. Below are few pointers.

1. Reduce the page margins (left and right)
2. Make the cells width fixed. This way, the text inside each cell will break downwards, if more characters found.
3. Change orientation to landscape, you will have a wider page.

Check the related articles and code sample on [Aspose.Words documentation website](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Applying+Formatting+to+Table,+Row+and+Cell).

Try the updated code sample below:

```
string dst = dataDir + "table.doc";

Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Set margins
doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 10;
//doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0;
doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.RightMargin = 10;
//doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0;

// Set oriantation
doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.Orientation = Aspose.Words.Orientation.Landscape;

Aspose.Words.Tables.Table table = builder.StartTable();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        builder.InsertCell();
        // Fixed width
        builder.CellFormat.Width = ConvertUtil.InchToPoint(0.5);
        builder.Write("Column : " + j);
    }
    builder.EndRow();
}
builder.EndTable();

// Set table auto fit behavior to fixed width columns
table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehavior.FixedColumnWidths);

doc.Save(dst, Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions.CreateSaveOptions(Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Doc));
```

I work with Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Nice Solution, but in my case i can't make cells with fixed width, the cell width will change as per character length of column header,                            is it possible to break columns to next page manually?

Comment: Columns cannot go to next page. You may divide it into two tables. Create first table, add page break and create second table.